# Constraints are not working at Buttons with Images Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

today i have set up some constraints in a view but there looks awful. Which Constraints have i to add (see screenshots)

[In XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diJOS.png)

[In Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9J7W.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: There's no constraints visible in your screenshot

Comment: Add constraints or use `UIStackView`s and then return with any specific problems you have once you reach a roadblock.

Comment: Are you trying this with collection view or just putting these four Images and buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement right, you need to have four images with labels below these individual images. If this is the case, you can use collection view whose cell contains a image view and a label. You can give the spacing between cells, size of cell and intercell spacing through delegates. Also just you need to specify image view and label constraints in collection view cell. Like for instance, image view placed horizontally centre and pinned to top of superview, label placed horizontally pinned to bottom of image view and top of label to give a gap between them.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the all images height and width, and given the leading, trailing, top and vertical spacing between label and images. Also fix the label height. You will given the min 4 and max 6 constraints for every fields.